# User Error: Prover 'alt-ergo' not found in why3.conf

Tags: frama-c, why3, alt-ergo

I am trying to test a function with Frama-c:

```
/*@
    ensures \result >= x && \result >= y;
    ensures \result == x || \result == y;
*/

int max( int x, int y){
    return (x>y) ? x : y;
}
```

After I installed all the requirements: OPAM, why3, alt-ergo
Whenever I execute *frama-c -wp fct.c* I receive:

```
[kernel] Parsing fct.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] User Error: Prover 'alt-ergo' not found in why3.conf
[wp] Goal typed_max_ensures : not tried
[wp] Goal typed_max_ensures_2 : not tried
[wp] User Error: Deferred error message was emitted during execution. 
See above messages for more information.
[kernel] Plug-in wp aborted: invalid user input.
```

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in [Frama-C's installation instructions](http://frama-c.com/install-21.1-Scandium.html#configuring-provers-for-frama-cwp), `why3` must be explicitely configured to check for available provers, through the `why3 config --detect` command (Note that, depending on the exact version of Why3 that you have installed, you might also use `why3 config --full-config` instead). You should see an output like:

```
Found prover Alt-Ergo version 2.0.0, OK.
... possibly other provers if you have installed them
Save config to /PATH/TO/HOME/.why3.conf
```

After that, you will be able to use the provers in Frama-C/WP

Comment: I tried the two commands but this is what I get:

`Found prover Coq version 8.12.0, but no Why3 libraries were compiled for it
Prover Alt-Ergo version 2.3.3 is not known to be supported.
Known versions for this prover: 2.3.1, 2.3.0.
Known old versions for this prover: .
1 prover(s) added (including 1 prover(s) with an unrecognized version)
Generating strategies:
Save config to /Users/aliissaoui/.why3.conf`

Comment: If you don't plan to use coq to terminate Frama-C or Why3 proofs, the first point shouldn't be a problem (but you might want to install the opam package `why3-coq`). The second point is simply an indication that your version of Why3 has not been tested againt your version of Alt-Ergo. Given the proximity with fully supported versions (2.3.3. vs 2.3.1), this shouldn't be a problem, but if you experience Alt-Ergo failures when doing proofs, you might consider downgrading to 2.3.1.

Comment: It seems like the command line has changed? I need `why3 config detect`, I have why3 v1.4.0.  It looks like the `opam install why3` tries to tell you this.  The final message is *=> Why3 provers setup: rm -f ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config detect*, but if you have never used opam it is not clear this is instructions for the user.  I thought it was a command that was performed by opam.

Comment: @artlessnoise yes, why3 has changed its command line syntax for detecting provers three times in the last three releases (but a developer -speaking on strict condition of anonymity - promised me that 1.4.0 was the last time). Normally, each Frama-C installation instructions contains the appropriate command line for the corresponding Why3 version.

Comment: The mentioned doc has expired. Here is another [doc](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/blob/master/INSTALL.md) related to Frama-c installation mentioned this. And in this doc, it says the command should be `why3 config detect`.